# Store file output in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file with two column as shown below

```
-34G     trendmar
+41G     trendmar
 1.4G    ttpsenet
 3.6G    tyibahco
-13M     uberhelp
+19M     uberhelp
-8.9G    umljgate
+9.2G    umljgate
```

I want to store it in dictionaries to do some mathematical operations but using the first column as value and second as key.

How could I do that?

Comment: What about duplicate keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read your file line by line, split on whitespace and use the elements in reverse to create a dictionary:

```
with open("your_file", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading
    # read it line by line, split and invert the fields to use as k:v for your dict
    data = dict(reversed(line.split()) for line in f)
    # {'trendmar': '+41G', 'ttpsenet': '1.4G', 'tyibahco': '3.6G',
    #  'uberhelp': '+19M', 'umljgate': '+9.2G'}
```

Beware that `dict` is essentially a hash map so it cannot have duplicate keys - values of duplicate keys will be overwritten with the latest value if they occur in the file.

**UPDATE:** If you want to preserve all the values you'll have to store them as lists, something like:

```
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)  # initiate all fields as lists
with open("your_file", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading
    for line in f:  # read the file line by line
        value, key = line.split()  # split the line to value and key
        data[key].append(value)  # append the value to the list for its key
```

And now your `data` will look like:

```
{'trendmar': ['-34G', '+41G'], 'ttpsenet': ['1.4G'], 'tyibahco': ['3.6G'],
 'uberhelp': ['-13M', '+19M'], 'umljgate': ['-8.9G', '+9.2G']}
```

**UPDATE 2:** If you want to sum the values instead you'll first need to convert them to floats, then use regular arithmetic operations to reach the final value, so first write a function to convert from the SI shorthand notation to native `float`:

```
QUANTIFIER_MAP = {"p": 1e15, "t": 1e12, "g": 1e9, "m": 1e6, "k": 1e3}
def si_to_float(number):
    try:
        last_char = number[-1].lower()
        if last_char in QUANTIFIER_MAP:
            return float(number[:-1]) * QUANTIFIER_MAP[last_char]
        return float(number)
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0
```

Now you can substitute `list` for a `float` when creating `data` and sum the values instead of appending:

```
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(float)  # initiate all fields as integers
with open("your_file", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading
    # read it line by line, split and invert the fields to use as k:v for your dict
    for line in f:  # read the file line by line
        value, key = line.split()  # split the line to value and key
        data[key] += si_to_float(value)  # convert to float and add to the value for this key
```

This will result in `data` as:

```
{'trendmar': 7000000000.0, 'ttpsenet': 1400000000.0, 'tyibahco': 3600000000.0,
 'uberhelp': 6000000.0, 'umljgate': 300000000.0}
```

If you want to return these values into a SI shortened notation, you'll have to write the opposite function of `si_to_float()` and then *convert* all your `data` values using it, i.e.:

```
QUANTIFIER_STACK = ((1e15, "p"), (1e12, "t"), (1e9, "g"), (1e6, "m"), (1e3, "k"))
def float_to_si(number):
    for q in QUANTIFIER_STACK:
        if number >= q[0]:
            return "{:.1f}".format(number / q[0]).rstrip("0").rstrip(".") + q[1].upper()
    return "{:.1f}".format(number).rstrip("0").rstrip(".")

# now lets traverse the previously created 'data' and convert its values:
for k, v in data.items():
    data[k] = float_to_si(v)
```

This will, finally, result in `data` containing:

```
{'trendmar': '7G', 'ttpsenet': '1.4G', 'tyibahco': '3.6G',
 'uberhelp': '6M', 'umljgate': '300M'}
```

Comment: This is better solution as this does not depend upon the number of space chars between the columns.

Comment: How i could get two value for same key in one list something like that
'trendmar': ['-34G', '+41G']

Comment: thanks its work but i have other request can i do mathematical operations between two values for samekey to just bring the Value difference

Comment: @KareemElSayed - Check the **Update 2** above ;)

Comment: thanks it's work so good i have just other thing if i want to do condition to  just print keys with values bigger than 1G how i could do that

Comment: @KareemElSayed - You can filter out the keys of any value you like before converting the values back to SI units, something like: `data = {k: v for k, v i n data.items() if v > 1e9}` to keep only values larger than 1G...

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("file.txt","r") as file:
    print({e.split("     ")[1]:e.split("     ")[0] for e in file})
```

You could use dictionary comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want more values to be associated with your keys for your calculations, this is my approach:

```
d = {}
with open("input.txt") as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    keys = sorted(set(line.split()[1] for line in lines))
    for key in keys:
        tempList = []
        for line in lines:
            if line.split()[1]==key:
                tempList.append(line.split()[0])
        d.update({key:tempList})

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'trendmar': ['-34G', '+41G'], 'uberhelp': ['-13M', '+19M'], 'umljgate': ['-8.9G', '+9.2G'], 'ttpsenet': ['1.4G'], 'tyibahco': ['3.6G']}
```

**Edit:**

If you wish to find the difference between two values, you can do it using the `literal_eval` function from `ast` module as follows:

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = {'trendmar': ['-34G', '+41G'], 'uberhelp': ['-13M', '+19M'], 'umljgate': ['-8.9G', '+9.2G'], 'ttpsenet': ['1.4G'], 'tyibahco': ['3.6G']}

first = 0
second = 1

diff = []
for key in d.keys():
    if len(d[key])==2:
        diff.append(key + " : " + str(literal_eval("".join([d[key][first][:-1] ," - (", d[key][second][:-1], ")"]))) + d[key][first][-1])
    else:
        diff.append(key + " : " + str(literal_eval(str(d[key][0][:-1]))) + d[key][0][-1])

print(diff)
```

Output:

```
['uberhelp : -32M', 'tyibahco : 3.6G', 'ttpsenet : 1.4G', 'umljgate : -18.1G', 'trendmar : -75G']
```

In the above example, we subtract the first from the second value. If you wish the opposite, then swap values of `first` and `second`.

Comment: this one its good for me but i try it show this error 
         IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Could you point out where exactly do you get this error? I tested the code with the data you provided. Each line of your file must have the value and the key, otherwise `split()` won't work.

Comment: i have other one can i do mathematical operations in the two value for same key to get the Value difference between to values

Comment: thanks so much that also work as well i will do some testing now and i still have any update about this case i will share it